# Excel: Add counting numbers to row for multiple identical serie numbers in other row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a spreadsheet with a row with serie numbers/ID's. Some of these serie numbers are identical. I want to assing a number to each of them. In yet another row there is a date, so I want the serie number with the first date to get number 1, with the second date number 2, etc. Please see example below:

[image: example]

My excelsheet has thousands of rows, so obviously I hope to be able to automate this action. Does anyone know a macrocode or formula to do this?

Your help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Must it be date count 1 < date count 2 < date count 3 and so on? Would you share some dummy data and clarify your question? Maybe add a picture(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Larissa,

Is there a possibility to use excel's sort tool to sort the table on dates, with lowest first?
If so, the Count column would be made by something the formula

```
=COUNTIF($B$9:B9;$B10)+1
```

assuming that we look at row 10 and ID is in column B. The first cell in the Count column would be an exception and have the formula =1

Regards,
Mats